# Long ping to devices on network and router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ping, packet-loss

I'm having some issues with my network and I believe its the modem/router combo comcast gave my parents. I'm trying to collect evidence to show to comcast.

When pinging other devices on my network (from multiple devices), including the router, I'm getting some delays I think are abnormal.

Pinging other computers on my network I get a solid 20ms ping with 120ms spikes.

Pinging the router I get an average of 50ms with dips of 9ms, frequent spikes to 75ms and one or two 170+ spikes.

Pinging google.com I get... better l pings... average of 30ms with spikes of 30 and dips to 11, which doesn't make sense, but, I do usually get at least 10% packet loss.

Does this sound like a router issue or isp issue?

Comment: First off, are the other devices simillarly impacted, pinging each other? I do recommend for many reasons, putting your own router behind your ISPs. it would eliminate concern about their device impacting local network performance. and let you discount local issues like cabling damage or environmental signal interference or other problems with this particular system.

Comment: It was for all of the devices. The ISP replaced the router and things are working better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this DOCSIS (that is, Internet service from a Cable TV provider)? If so, first look up the real manufacturer and model# of the router (look for a label on the back or bottom of it) and make sure it's not on the [badmodems.com](https://badmodems.com/) list of known-bad modems based on the crappy Intel Puma 6 chipset that has known latency problems. If it's on the list, that's enough reason to have them replace it.

You need to look up the real manufacturer and model# if your ISP has slapped their own branding on it. For example, Comcast uses names like "Xfinity xFi" or "Xfinity XB3" for a number of different routers from different manufacturers, that all more or less meet the same specifications.

The client device you're pinging from…is it on wired Ethernet or Wi-Fi? Ping time on wired Ethernet should be about 0.3ms. Ping time over one Wi-Fi hop (like pinging your router's LAN IP from a wireless client) on a reasonably clean channel and otherwise idle Wi-Fi network should be about 3ms. But Wi-Fi is prone to interference and going off-channel to scan, so spikes into the low hundreds of milliseconds are common.

If this is over Wi-Fi, then to be fair to the ISP, try to eliminate poor radio signal/noise conditions as a factor. Put your client device between 2-5m of the router, with clear line-of-sight. Use a tool like inSSIDer to help you pick the cleanest channels to put your router's Wi-Fi radios on. Make sure everything else on your Wi-Fi network is idle, and that you're not using any kind of repeaters or range extenders for this test.

Comment: After talking with the ISP I was able to confirm that this router was 8 years old... even though they gave it to us 4 years ago. They're replacing it soon.